# SSH Permission Denied (PublicKey) -VVV included, not typical error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, command-line-interface

An ec2 instance I've accessed just this morning now is inaccessible (by ssh). I was trying to troubleshoot why I couldn't scp a file onto the ec2, and something I did seems to have messed with permissions or something. I suspect it is server side, but not sure how to proceed. Here is the -vvv response

```
ssh -i aooo-2018.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-132-32-39.compute-1.amazonaws.com -vvv
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/aooo/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/aooo/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ec2-54-163-60-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-163-60-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.163.60.93] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file aooo-2018.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file aooo-2018.pem-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/aooo/.ssh/id_rsa2 type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aooo/.ssh/id_rsa2-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-54-163-60-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/aooo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file     /Users/aooo/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-54-163-60-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs:     ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms:     curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc:     umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ydCe5YP/SFw7iYqA0xrweFYySjVeSW/q42N0O/kanbg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/aooo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/aooo/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-54-163-60-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/aooo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/aooo/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 54.163.60.93
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-163-60-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/aooo/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key:  (0x7fbffcc0bcf0), agent
debug2: key:  (0x7fbffcc0bf30), agent
debug2: key:  (0x7fbffcc0c170), agent
debug2: key: aooo-2018.pem (0x0), explicit
debug2: key: /Users/aooo/.ssh/id_rsa2 (0x7fbffce0bf70), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: 
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: 
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: 
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: aooo-2018.pem
debug2: storing passphrase in keychain
debug3: Search for existing item with query: {
    acct = "aooo-2018.pem";
    agrp = "com.apple.ssh.passphrases";
    class = genp;
labl = "SSH: aooo-2018.pem";
nleg = 1;
"r_Ref" = 1;
svce = OpenSSH;
}
debug3: Item already exists in the keychain, updating.
debug1: identity added to agent: aooo-2018.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA     SHA256:60XlRndJqej5HngOueWypkWD2nSebASQYsoc7Am1rF4
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/aooo/.ssh/id_rsa2
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I know this is a common question but no other post has solved the problem. Let me know if the -vvv tells you something that I'm missing

Comment: Does your ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config file have a mapping from ec2-54-132-32-39.compute-1.amazonaws.com to ec2-54-163-60-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com? Sounds like a problem.

Comment: err sorry I edited the response to change the server id in case that was a security problem. You can assume its all the same number

Comment: You might have the user `ec2-user` locked on the server side (check `/var/log/auth.log` to be sure). You need to unlock the user and try to `ssh` again.

Comment: How can I check the /var/log/auth.log if I'm not able to ssh?

Comment: Isn't your server accessible from the console( or another user)?

Answer (score 0):

SSH has gone thru each  of your public keys and each one was rejected by the remote server. Either you have corrupted your existing key, deleted it, or you are using the wrong username for login (client side).

If you have broken the server side SSH, then you will need to manually repair the server.

If you are using a modern version of an Amazon AMI, then you probably have the SSM agent installed. You can connect to your instance using SSM and this does not require anything other than SSM configured on the server (no security group ports, ssh server daemon, nothing) AND an EC2 profile with SSM permissions.

[What Is AWS Systems Manager?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html)

Read this blog post for more information about accessing your instance using SSM:

[New – AWS Systems Manager Session Manager for Shell Access to EC2 Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-session-manager/)